# Static Widgets with a PageView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

Is there a way to make a few widgets *static* upon a `PageView` change?

I know I can make one widget static by wrapping the `Scaffold` within a `Container`, and have that `Container` have something like a `decoration`, but I don't know how to **add more widgets that do not change when a page changes**.

I have a few widgets that change when the page view changes, but then I want to have, say a `Button` below those widgets that stay still, but
if I put the same `Button` in every widget, it will swipe through and show two buttons when I change the page momentarily.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out, I thought the `PageView` can only be assigned to the `body` property of a `Scaffold`, but wrapping it within a `Column` like this works. So just add the static widgets within the `Column`!

```
return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(), // For background.
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Flexible(child: pageView),
            // Static Widgets here!
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```